# No internet via Ethernet connection on Debian 10 buster

Tags: linux, networking, debian, dns

I am new to linux and i am currently running debian 10 buster on a beaglebone black. I am trying to connect my beaglebone black(BBB) to the internet via a Ethernet to 2.0-usb cable to my laptop witch is connected wireless to my router.

I have installed the latest image of debian(AM3358 Debian 10.3 2020-04-06 4GB eMMC IoT Flasher) from https://beagleboard.org/latest-images[enter link description here](https://beagleboard.org/latest-images)

so its a fresh install of the operating system.I can tell that the internet connection is not working because i cant ping goolge.com. When i do i get the following error message:

```
ping: www.google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

After some google searches on the issue some people have said to edit the /etc/resolv.conf file and add `nameserver 8.8.8.8` 
however my resolv.conf file is completely empty and when i added it in and restarted my BBB but i still could not ping google.

some people have also said to edit the /etc/network/interfaces file and add in the following:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.100 # some static IP you want
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1
```

sadly, adding this did not work either.
Any help resolving this issue will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you try pinging an IP address? If you ping 8.8.8.8 and get replies, you know the internet is working, but something is wrong with your DNS setup.

Comment: Hey Sam, I tried to ping 8.8.8.8 and i got this error:PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 169.254.47.23 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable.Any idea on how i can fix my DNS setup?

Comment: If you can't even ping an IP address, something's wrong with your IP configuration. If you aren't able to get an IP assigned to you via DHCP, then you will need to manually set one that is on the same network as your router.

Comment: The only ip address i can ping is 192.168.7.2 which is the default ip address for BeagleBone Black